# UIButton - UIImage bounce

Tags: uibutton, ios6

Do you know how to make this buttons bounce?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ku1lB9etiN8

Comment: Are you talking about the smaller buttons coming out from beneath the green button?

Answer (score 0):

They used some of the [UIView animateWithDuration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a) methods. My guess is that that started the buttons behind the large green button, animated them to spin, then animated their position. This is a custom thing they built, and you'll have to build it from scratch as well.